# Paypal /cgi-bin/webscr form data

Tags: php, html, forms, paypal

Apologies for the newbie question but we all start somewhere.

I've set up a site with paypal payment and cart.  Works fine.  I get the returned tx value and need to post a form to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

```
<form method=post action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_notify-synch">
<input type="hidden" name="tx" value="<?php echo $_GET['tx']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="at" value="_hidden for obvious reasons_">
<input type="submit" value="PDT">
</form>
```

I can do this but the data is displayed on the page https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr.  How can I get the form data into my site rather than on the PayPal site.

I hope this makes sense,

Answer (score -2):

cURL!!
Sorry, hope this didn't waste anyone's time.

The answer is at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/

Comment: Link is broken, so this question is not usable anymore.